# remove p and span wrapper from billing shipping and form woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

How I can remove the `<p>` wrapper around the form fields of woocommerce? I'm trying to customize the form but without success. Can anyone help me? 
I've noticed that all the fields are wrapped inside a `<p>` tag, and the inputs fields are wrapped with a `<span>` but this will break all the bootstrap layout and I'm looking for a hook that can remove this.

EDIT:

Here is the forms code, as you can see there isn't any `<p>` or `<span>` tag that can be removed but only the `do_action` that will render the form fields.

```
<?php
/**
 * Checkout Form
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', $checkout );

// If checkout registration is disabled and not logged in, the user cannot checkout.
if ( ! $checkout->is_registration_enabled() && $checkout->is_registration_required() && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_must_be_logged_in_message', __( 'You must be logged in to checkout.', 'woocommerce' ) ) );
    return;
}

?>

<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <?php if ( $checkout->get_checkout_fields() ) : ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details' ); ?>

        <div class="row" id="customer_details">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing' ); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping' ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review_heading' ); ?>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <h3 id="order_review_heading"><?php esc_html_e( 'Your order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review' ); ?>

    <div id="order_review" class="woocommerce-checkout-review-order col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review' ); ?>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review' ); ?>

</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', $checkout ); ?>
```

```
<?php
/**
 * Checkout billing information form
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-billing.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.6.0
 * @global WC_Checkout $checkout
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
?>
<!-- <div class="woocommerce-billing-fields"> -->
    <?php if ( wc_ship_to_billing_address_only() && WC()->cart->needs_shipping() ) : ?>

        <h3><?php esc_html_e( 'Billing &amp; Shipping', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>

    <?php else : ?>

        <h3><?php esc_html_e( 'Billing details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', $checkout ); ?>

    <div class="form-row woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper">
        <?php
        $fields = $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' );

        foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
            woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) );
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', $checkout ); ?>
<!-- </div> -->

<?php if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && $checkout->is_registration_enabled() ) : ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-account-fields">
        <?php if ( ! $checkout->is_registration_required() ) : ?>

            <div class="create-account form-group">
                <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox">
                    <input class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox form-control" id="createaccount" <?php checked( ( true === $checkout->get_value( 'createaccount' ) || ( true === apply_filters( 'woocommerce_create_account_default_checked', false ) ) ), true ); ?> type="checkbox" name="createaccount" value="1" /> <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Create an account?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
                </label>
            </div>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_registration_form', $checkout ); ?>

        <?php if ( $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'account' ) ) : ?>

            <div class="create-account">
                <?php foreach ( $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'account' ) as $key => $field ) : ?>
                    <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) ); ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_registration_form', $checkout ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have full scope to customize the WooCommerce form. Copy the /woocommerce folder from /plugins and paste into your /themes folder. Then find out the `<p>` tag and remove that, if not work you can use [wpautop](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop). You can also remove the `<span>` tag by customizing the form. I have done it from my /themes folder, so try to customize it from the /themes folder.

Comment: I've already copied all the templates in my theme woocommerce folder. The problem is that there isn't any `<p>` tag inside the various forms templates, the fields are generated using a function and the official documentations are explaining only how to add or remove fields, but no explainantion about the fields markup are present

Comment: There has no way to use `wpautop`?

Comment: no, because the wrapper is added by a woocommerce core function that output forms

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field', 'updated_woocommerce_form_field' );

function updated_woocommerce_form_field( $field ) {
   
    $field = preg_replace(
        '#<p class="form-row (.*?) (.*?) (.*?) (.*?)" (.*?)><span [A-Za-z]+="[A-Za-z]+-[A-Za-z]+-[A-Za-z]+">(.*?)</span></p>#',
        '$6',
        $field
    );
    
    return $field;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_text', 'custom_woocommerce_form_field_text', 10, 4);
function custom_woocommerce_form_field_text($field, $key, $args, $value){
    // Измените HTML-вывод для типа поля 'text'
    $output = '<input type="' . esc_attr($args['type']) . '" name="' . esc_attr($key) . '" id="' . esc_attr($args['id']) . '" value="' . esc_attr($value) . '" ' . implode(' ', $args['input_class']) . ' />';
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: You should add explanation.